# How to write a PL/SQL function have parameter similar to greatest function

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle/PLSQL, the greatest function returns the greatest value in a list of expressions. The syntax for greatest function is

```
greatest( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n )).
```

How can I write my function with unlimit parameter like this:

```
myfunction(param1 , param2,...param_n)
```

Comment: +1 I wish this would be added to PL/SQL :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simulate var args using a table type as the parameter.

```
create or replace type VARGS as table of varchar2(32767);
```

You can then use this type as the last parameter of the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function FNC_COUNT_WITH_NAMES
   ( P_NAMES IN VARGS )
   RETURN number
IS
RT_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
  select count(*) INTO rt_count from employees where name IN 
    ( 
       select * from TABLE(p_names))
    );
   return rt_count;
END;
```

Client code would call it with:

```
exec FNC_COUNT_WITH_NAMES (vargs('Brian','Mike','John','David', 'Bob'));
```

or

```
select FNC_COUNT_WITH_NAMES (vargs('Brian','Mike','John','David', 'Bob')) from dual;
```

Comment: Since you're using a string in sql, you can limit the string to 4000 characters